# lineEdit замена символа на "*"

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Делаю окошко с вводом пин-кода. Имеется следующий вид: изначально в `lineedit` находится строка типа "_ _ _ _". Далее каждое нижнее подчеркивание мы заменяем на цифру которая вводится с виртуальной клавиатуры, и имеет, например, следующий вид - "1 2 _ _". Через доли секунды нужно заменить цифры на звездочки и получить "* * _ _". Т.е. при вводе цифры мы видим ее и она прячется за звездочку.

Есть следующий слот:

```
void uRent::s1(const QString &i)
{
     QString line = ui->lineEdit->text();
     int index = line.indexOf('_');
     line.replace(index, 1, i);
     ui->lineEdit->insert(line);
     QThread::msleep(1000);
     line.replace(index, 1, '*');
     ui->lineEdit->setText(line);
}
```

Но при выполнении он ждет секунду и потом вместо цифры сразу вставляет звездочку. Есть подозрение что `QThread::msleep(1000);` выполняется не в середине тела слота, а сразу и только потом выполняются все функции. Так ли это и как можно реализовать выше описанное?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При установке нового значения в `QLineEdit`, производится создание и отправка события `QPaintEvent` в соответствующий виджет. Вызов же метода `QThread::msleep()` блокирует доставку объекта обозначенного события.

Итого, получается:

1. первое событие с цифрой создаётся и отправляется в диспетчер
   событий;
2. `sleep()` производит блокировку на перерисовку виджета;
3. второе событие со звёздочкой создаётся и отправляется в диспетчер
   событий;
4. оба события выполняются сразу друг за другом, что не
   позволяет на глаз увидеть изменения.

Измените свой код на что-нибудь с использованием таймера. Например, так:

```
void uRent::s1(const QString &i) {
     QString line = ui->lineEdit->text();
     int index = line.indexOf('_');
     line.replace(index, 1, i);
     ui->lineEdit->insert(line);

     QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
     timer->setSingleShot(true);
     timer->setInterval(500);

     connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this,timer,index]() {
         QString line = ui->lineEdit->text();
         line.replace(index, 1, '*');
         ui->lineEdit->setText(line);
         timer->deleteLater();
     });

     timer->start();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @Madisson, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скажите, а что это за выражение [this,timer,index]() и где про это можно прочитать? Я впервые встречаю такой способ описания слота.

Comment: Это анонимная (лямбда) функция. Почитать про это можно, например, [здесь в целом по C++](https://habrahabr.ru/post/66021/) и [здесь по Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru).